# libCURL and persistant cookies

Tags: cookies, libcurl

I want to scrape some information from a pokerplatforms webpage.

For that I need to login (post) on the https webpage "www.name.com". But the information is placed on a subdomain "poker.name.com". The login works pretty well but when i GET the site from the subdomain libcurl sets up a new connection obv with new cookies. Then I get a page reminding me that i have to log in.

Now my question is how i can force libcurl to use the same connection or at least the same cookie to GET the page from the subdomain.

EDIT:
Not the solution to my quetsion but works fine: I just logged in to the subdomain. The login skript exists there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enable cookies for a libcurl handle, you can then just re-use that handle on subsequent requests and libcurl will use cookies automatically.

If you insist on closing the handles and creating new ones, then [CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCOOKIEJAR) is the option you want to save the cookies into a file and [CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCOOKIEFILE) can then subsequently read them back again from such a file. Alternatively, you can use libcurl's [share interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-share.html) to have multiple handles share cookies.

Then, in order to "properly" mimic a browser on a site like this, you really should record the HTTP headers sent and received during a manual session so that you can be sure your program uses the same URLs and data as your browser did.

Comment: Nice when im right you are the author of libCURL. Thanks your lib is great. But i have a major problem with it. Would be kind if you could have a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592328/err-remove-thread-state-linker-error-on-libcurl-usage

Comment: I am, yes, but don't mistake stackoverflow for a support forum for all your problems.

Comment: I am creating a new curl for every request and destroying it afterwards. I need it to be concurrent in my application (under certain circumstances this happens), so just passing the old handle won't work. Can you describe a bit on how to pass a cookie from an old curl?

Comment: If I need to close and create new handles after each request, wouldn't saving the cookies manually using CURLINFO_COOKIELIST and then setting them using CURLOPT_COOKIELIST work ?

Comment: Yes you can use the `*COOKIELIST` features.