# "_ERR_remove_thread_state" linker error on libcurl usage

Tags: openssl, libcurl

1. Got OpenSSL (Win32) here http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
2. Downloaded and compiled libCURL wit following flags

   - USE_SSLEAY;
   - USE_OPENSSL;
   - CURL_DISABLE_LDAP;
3. Included headers and libs in my project

... and now i get this ugly error.

```
1>libcurl.lib(ssluse.obj) : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_ERR_remove_thread_state".
1>C:\[...].exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgelöste externe Verweise.
```

I guess this should remind me of a missing lib, but i think there are none. Google results dont help me any further.  Any ideas?

Greets Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a broken openssl package to me. ERR_remove_thread_state() was introduced in 1.0.0 and the libcurl source code checks for the version and only uses that function on a new enough openssl... You can easily see that yourself in curl/lib/ssluse.c